Qt lupdate интернационализация приложения
Я работаю в Visual Studio 2022 и по учебнику дошёл до интернационализации приложений с помощью lupdate. В какую папку мне закинуть .pro файл, чтобы всё переводилось? Я не уверен, что .pro файл вообще подключен к моему проекту.

.pro файл
SOURCES += main.cpp
HEADERS += MainHeader.h
QT += core gui widgets multimedia multimediawidgets printsupport
CONFIG += c++20
TRANSLATIONS = QtLanguage_ru.ts
lupdate main.cpp -ts main_ru.ts

main.cpp
#include"MainHeader.h" // Заголовочный файл со всеми подключенными классами
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTranslator translator;
    translator.load("QtLanguage_ru", "."); // не загружается файл

    app.installTranslator(&translator);
    QLabel lbl(QObject::tr("Hello")); // не переводится надпись
    lbl.show();
    return app.exec();

}

MainHeader.h
#pragma once
#ifndef MAINHEADER
#define MAINHEADER
#include<qapplication.h>
#include<qlabel.h>

#include<qpushbutton.h>
#include<qradiobutton.h>
#include<qcheckbox.h>

#include<qlayout.h>
#include<qsettings.h>
#include<qdrag.h>
#include<qpoint.h>
#include<qmimedata.h>
#include<qpixmap>
#include<qevent.h>
#include<qtranslator.h>
#endif MAINHEADER

Я буду премного благодарен любой помощи!

До этого вообще не работал с .pro файлами. Только с заголовочными файлами программу запускал.

а где сам QtLanguage_ru.qm лежит? стопудово не в каталоге запуска а в каталоге с проектом же
